# What is the maximum current the GPIO pins can output?

Tags: gpio

What is the maximum amount of current that can be pulled from a single GPIO pin?

Does the maximum current decrease if current is being pulled from multiple GPIO pins?

From my research, I've found:

- An [Arduino](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/DigitalPins) can pull 40 mA
- People on the [forums](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=41077) hint at 50 mA  as an answer
- Searching the [data sheet](http://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf) returns no results
- Some discussion was brought up on [electronics.stackexchange.com](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/80437/using-a-microcontroller-to-turn-on-led-strip?noredirect=1#comment157839_80437)

Comment: Related: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/1130/40

Comment: Related: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/51615/19949

Comment: "Arduino" is a platform, not a device. Different Arduino micro-controllers have different specifications!

Answer (score 57):

> This answer is OBSOLETE. The Pi 3.3V rail is widely assumed to provide 50mA, but this is not officially documented for recent Pi models. The original Pi has an on-board linear regulator which was limited, but the B+ and later have a switch mode regulator which can supply more. The regulator chip (which supplies both 3.3V and 1.8V) is rated at 1A. [Raspberry Pi Power Limitations](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations)

This is an interesting question because it has a not so concrete answer.

The power rails...

- The 5 V rail appears to passed straight through from the USB and the current is therefore limited to whatever the USB port can supply minus the current being drawn by the board. [(Source 1)](http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals#Power_pins)
- The 3.3 V rail can supply a maximum of 50 mA. [(Source 1)](http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals#Power_pins)

The GPIO...

So here it gets a little foggier. There isn't any current limiting features on the board, so if you demand a certain amount of current from a pin, it will attempt to drive it until something breaks.

Saying that, from the research I've done, the absolute maximum you should draw from a single pin is 16 mA. HOWEVER, a pin is driven by the 3.3 V rail, which can't drive more than 50 mA! So it's a balancing act. It is recommended though, that a series resistor is placed on the GPIO to limit the current and prevent damage. The board was really designed to be buffered before being connect to peripheral devices. [(Source 2)](http://www.mosaic-industries.com/embedded-systems/microcontroller-projects/raspberry-pi/gpio-pin-electrical-specifications#rpi-gpio-input-voltage-and-output-current-limitations) [(Source 3)](http://www.scribd.com/doc/101830961/GPIO-Pads-Control2)

Source 2 and 3 link to pages that explain the operation of the Pi's driver set up on the GPIO. It's worth a read though may be a bit outside the scope of the question.

To summarise from another source, the GPIO output current is...

> A maximum of 16mA per pin with the total current from all pins not exceeding 50mA[sic] [(Source 4)](http://www.thebox.myzen.co.uk/Raspberry/Understanding_Outputs.html)

Comment: @Milliways: It seems you've made the same edit to several answers here. The OP's question was re *max current for GPIO pins*; your edit addresses the current capacity of the 3V3 regulator. I realize they're *related*, but I'm not clear on how the regulator capacity makes answers re GPIO max current obsolete???

Answer (score 11):

> This answer is OBSOLETE. The Pi 3.3V rail is widely assumed to provide 50mA, but this is not officially documented for recent Pi models. The original Pi has an on-board linear regulator which was limited, but the B+ and later have a switch mode regulator which can supply more. The regulator chip (which supplies both 3.3V and 1.8V) is rated at 1A. [Raspberry Pi Power Limitations](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations)

According to [this blog](http://www.thebox.myzen.co.uk/Raspberry/Understanding_Outputs.html)

> When the Pi was designed, they used a figure of 3mA per GPIO pins in determining if the regulator could supply enough current.

17 pins at 3 mA each means the power regulator is only rated for 50 mA

50 mA / 17 =~ 3 mA

The author of the same blog suggest that 16 mA be the maximum pulled from any 1 pin, and that 50 mA as the maximum from all pins.

Comment: Thanks! Here is an [archive link](https://archive.is/eiX4T) in case the link above stops working.

Answer (score 5):

On the **official** [Compute Module data sheet release 2](https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/master/hardware/computemodule/datasheets/rpi_DATA_CM_2p0.pdf) page 14:

[image: IOL and IOH]

The datasheet is applied to both CM1 and CM3, so as BCM2835 and BCM2837 when VDD_IO=3.3V.  According to the table, It is safe to drive up to 18mA and sink up to 17mA by GPIO.

Comment: Dead link. New link for v4 is here -- https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/cm4/cm4-datasheet.pdf

Answer (score 1):

A Raspberry Pi pin (GPIO) gives me a 23 mA max current (3.43 V) when I set it to on (using pi4j or RPI.GPIO). I think the maximum permitted is 30 mA, otherwise your Raspberry Pi is dead.

You can check it yourself by using a [multimeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimeter) connected in series.

Comment: that 23ma could most likely be explained by ohms law with the voltage drop on your multimeter, not the Rpi's actual capability. Current = Voltage / Resistance And no current meter has 0 ohm resistance. Just a little bit of theory for the day :)

Comment: @user30946: 23mA at 3.43V would give 149 Ohm. A current meter which such a high resistance would be useless and would burn out on any medium current.

Answer (score 1):

> This answer is OBSOLETE. The Pi 3.3V rail is widely assumed to provide 50mA, but this is not officially documented for recent Pi models. The original Pi has an on-board linear regulator which was limited, but the B+ and later have a switch mode regulator which can supply more. The regulator chip (which supplies both 3.3V and 1.8V) is rated at 1A. [Raspberry Pi Power Limitations](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations)

---

> A maximum of 16mA per pin with the total current from all pins not
>   exceeding 51mA

From the Gert himself!

So, if your project is only using 4 pins, make sure that your current settings do no exceed the 16mA per pin and all driven together don't exceed the total of 51mA. I believe that the 16mA is also configurable somewhere.

Generally, you should be using a buffer of sorts or a transistor to drive things like LEDs or relays. If you have a bit of a wiring problem or component failure, your board and or CPU may let out the magic smoke.

I know HP used to make some marvelous low current LEDs back in the day. They used to need 2mA of current and a forward voltage for their red one of around 2V, so you would need a small resistor to limit its current consumption and protect the CPU pin.

I see Vishay have a similar type device, and I suppose [Kingbright](http://www.kingbrightusa.com/images/catalog/SPEC/WP710A10LSRD.pdf) do too.

**To calculate the current limiting resistor:**

```
resVal = (Vsupply - VforwardLED)/currentLimit

so... for a 3.3V RPi pin, LED spec says 2V, our limit is 2mA, we get:
resVal = (3.3 - 2)/0.002

resVal = 650 Ohms

Safely round that up to the closest E12/E24 resistor value of 680 Ohms
```

Here is the [values table and color codes](http://www.4qdtec.com/colcode.html) if needed.

Enjoy your RPi! Everything should have more LEDS!