# Connecting RPi GPIO into a relay that draw high ampere

Tags: electronics

So straight to the problem

I need to connect My RPi's GPIO to a (or some) relay(s) that consume around 30 - 60 Amps to fire up and RPi GPIO only give around 16 mA/Pin(Accroding to [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/9313/20001)).

My question is,what is the safest and best way to connect the GPIO to a relay with 60A of input ?

Thankyou

P.S. : I dont know (almost) anything about electricity and english is not my native language.So i'm sorry if there are any mistakes around here

Comment: You must be mistaken. A relays control circuit taking 30 Amps sound terribly wrong.

Comment: 30 Amps consumption for a relay? Please review that.

Comment: Yeah i kinda choked on my tea when i read this, check your power consumption, because anything higher than even .5ma pull i use and external plugpack.

Comment: Reviewed,and @Pariah sorry for your tea

Comment: By any chance what is the application for? Because there is no way a raspberry pi will ever output more than 15-50mA on any one pin at any given time, in saying that look up a digitally controlled relay, H-bridge or a irf640-Irfz44 (mosfet) for controlling a switch of any sort.

Comment: @Pariah actually i'm trying to controlling relay on a Motorcycle electric starter system.What i know (from my friend who know electronics better than me ) that relay will need at least 30A to fired up and i think it is not a digital controlled relay and i'm trying to control it digitally from Pi

Comment: Ah that makes better sense now, nah id look at a way of isolating a digital control signal from the raspberry pi to actually control the relay circuit, for example look for a relay or switch (like the mentioned mosfets above) because all the mosftet needs is a digital signal to connect the ground and boom you have a viable circuit, but look for high power mosfets that can support 30A+ inputs, because most mosfets only need a small digital signal to complete the connection but thats something id look into if i were you.

Answer (score -2):

Add a transistor to your rpi and the relay to the transistor. This should work.

In case you don't know as much as me - watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-td7YT-Pums then you do.

If you could supply some numbers of the parts you are using, we can throw together a drawing for you. But right now it would just be a search in the dark.

Comment: A diagram and a little more detail would improve your answer and help others who may not know as much as you do.