# Physical on off switch to digital

Tags: gpio, switches

I have a raspberry pi 2 model b and I am trying to build a digital on of switch, which means that I would like to get rid of this physical one ( Currently it controls a police type flashing light)

[image: ofOff]

and Id like the light to switched on/off using software and GPIO pins.
I have a breadboard with all the necessary equipment (wires, resistor and etc) . Could anyone please draw or show me basic circuit of how I could build it?

The power comes from a battery pack inside the light itself

Answer (score 0):

How are you planing on powering the "police like flashing light"? If the power from the raspberry is enough you could write a simple python script that powers on and off the light.

Comment: no the batterypack is inside the light, I just would like to connect the on&off switch to control it from the raspberry pi

Comment: Check this other post out, should be the solution you're looking for .
http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41173/how-to-switch-on-off-a-circuit-using-gpio?rq=1