# How to set GPIO pin that requires 5v HIGH with 3v input?

Tags: gpio, voltage

I have a circuit block (Let's name it as block A) with a set of GPIO pins. The HIGH state of these GPIOs are 3v.
I have a motor bridge that requires 5v input to set its (motor bridge's) GPIO to HIGH.

What I am trying is, when the GPIO pin in block A is HIGH, make the motor bridge's GPIO pin HIGH as well. When I connect the two pins directly (block A pin to motor bridges pin) motor bridge circuit did not detect the pin as HIGH. However, when I give 5v input to the bridge's GPIO pin it works. And I know block A GPIO's are only outputting 3v (when set to HIGH).

So how can I solve this? Do I need to use something like a step-up transformer or use a transistor as a switch?

Is there a simple way to solve this?

Appreciate your thoughts.

EDIT: (Additional info) I have a 5V power supply to the motor bridge circuit. That can be used if required.

Comment: Not a Pi specific question.  This applies to all devices which provide less than 5V at the GPIO.  Use a transistor as a switch.  Feed it 3V3 and it will switch 5V.  Look online for circuits.  Or buy a voltage translater chip.

Comment: Oh, is this a duplicate then? https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41173/how-to-switch-on-off-a-circuit-using-gpio?newreg=b100db79d2444a7ab62c59f16e85ed6f

Comment: Or a level shifter https://thepihut.com/products/sparkfun-logic-level-converter-bi-directional?variant=41531949908163&currency=GBP

Comment: Look up the thresholds of the thresholds of the IC families such as HCT. Post a schematic if you can.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How To Switch On/Off A Circuit using GPIO](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41173/how-to-switch-on-off-a-circuit-using-gpio)