# How do I change the drive strength on GPIO

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio

I believe you can change the drive strengths of the GPIO outputs. I need to drive one LED at 16mA. However I cant find anywhere where you can do this. I am using the RPI.GPIO python module so it would be handy if this could be done in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GPIO source/sink current can be programmed to be 2 mA to 16 mA. The hardware default is 8 mA, but the OS may change it to something else.

For details and caveats, see: http://www.scribd.com/doc/101830961/GPIO-Pads-Control2

Comment: Thanks. I need to set bits 2:0 = 111b. Any idea how I would go about doing that?

Comment: here are code samples: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/1154/7274