# Where is the GPIO header file ("linux/gpio.h")?

Tags: debian, gpio, software-development

I've been reading about the [linux GPIO](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio.txt) functions and tried to make a small example using the function `gpio_is_valid`, but the compile fails because it can't find `linux/gpio.h`.

```c
#include <iostream>

#include <linux/gpio.h>

int main()
{
    const bool is17Valid = !!gpio_is_valid(17);
    if (is17Valid)
    {
        std::cout << "17 is valid!" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "17 is *not* valid!" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Is `linux/gpio.h` available on the Raspberry Pi? If not, are none of the functions described in the linux documentation available?

I'm using the original Debian "Squeeze" image.

Comment: Which distro are you using?

Comment: Did you setup up the linker?What are the error messages? Would "return 0;" be pointless since it isn't C?

Comment: I'm using the original Debian "Squeeze" image and the error message was, can't find "linux/gpio.h".

Comment: You have to interact with the GPIO as `root`. Are you `root`?

Comment: @Haskeller: C++ is backwards compatible with C, so you still need `return 0;` because you're in a function that returns an `int`.  Omitting this results in a compiler error.

Comment: None of the driving examples I can find use `linux/gpio.h`; have you got an example of one that does?

Comment: @Jivings Completely irrelevant!

Comment: @AlexChamberlain: I was guessing that `linux/gpio.h` is inaccessible without root access. I don't see how that is irrelevant.

Comment: @Jivings That would be an awful plan! Root permissions should be needed to access GPIO (they are memory mapped), but you don't want to be running `gcc` as root!

Comment: @AlexChamberlain Yeah true. That wouldn't be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need `linux/gpio.h` - as you stated in a comment, the RPi repo has a pretty redundant version of it.

The GPIO's are memory-mapped, which you can read about it in [How does memory-mapped I/O addressing work?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/600/86).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're compiling on the Pi itself, you'll probably need to install some development packages, as precompiled binaries don't need header files present to run (so they're not installed by default.)

I think in this case the name of the package you want is probably `linux-headers`, which will put gpio.h into `/usr/include/linux/gpio.h`.  Because the file sits in `/usr/include` it means you don't need to specify this part of the path either in your code or to the compiler, so `#include <linux/gpio.h>` as you have there is enough, once you've installed the correct package.

Comment: Has anyone tested this?

Comment: Through a series of links I managed to find the following - https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-patches/include/linux/gpio.h - it looks like the functions aren't implemented anyway!